# Amend <span>content</span> by getting current webpage URL

Tags: javascript, html, class, url

Is it possible to amend the content depending on the URL of the opened webpage?
For example I have 50 cloned pages with slightly different content, let's assume that each row is the content of a different page

```html
<!--Page Paris-->
<span class="address">Street 1, House 1</span>
<span class="hours">10:00-18:00</span>

<!--Page Berlin-->
<span class="address">Street 2, House 2</span>
<span class="hours">10:00-19:00</span>

<!--Page London-->
<span class="address">Street 3, House 3</span>
<span class="hours">10:00-20:00</span>
```

And I need the content to be pulled from the script:

- if the page address is https://mywebsite.com/paris/ the page should be like this

```html
<span class="address">Street 1, House 1</span>
<span class="hours">10:00-18:00</span>
```

- if the page address is https://mywebsite.com/berlin/

```html
<span class="address">Street 2, House 1</span> 
<span class="hours">10:00-19:00</span>
```

- if the page address is https://mywebsite.com/london/

```html
<span class="address">Street 3, House 3</span>
<span class="hours">10:00-20:00</span>
```

This way I could use only 1 page instead of 50 and the content would just depend on the page URL.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by playing with the `window.location` object using a javascript script.

I mean, if you have the link in that way you can get the current site path with

```
let mypath = window.location.pathname // this returns 'ccc' if you are on https://mywebsite.com/ccc/
```

so you can add a script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', start);

function start(){
   let mypath = window.location.pathname; // get the current site path
   let span = document.querySelector(".address"); // get the span object
   span.innerText = mypath; // set the span text with the current path
}
</script>
```

For add the hour you have to act in a similar way but playing with the `Date` in javascript

#### EDIT

If you want instead to add predefined text in the span insteat than the current url path you can define an object containing the text. For example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', start);
const myTexts{
   '/path_of_the_site/longer_path' : 'custom text',
   '/paris': ' paris via',
   '/spain': 'spain via'
}
function start(){
   let myPath = window.location.pathname; // get the current site path
   span.innerText = myTexts[myPath]; // set the span text from the object based on the path
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @mat-c , thanks a lot for your comment. i believe i failed to formulate my question correctly first time. Now it's fixed. I need the predefine the content for <span class="address"></span> and <span class="hours"></span> in script for all 50 pages. Not to copy-paste the URL from address bar. Meaning if current pages is  https://mywebsite.com/paris/ then <span class="address">Street 1, House 1</span> etc. for all locations. Do you think it's possible? Thanks again for your help and sorry for misleading initial info.

Comment: @scholar2020 Here you go, maybe this one is what you were searching